# How can I add this extra icon in toolbar for some fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am making an android application which have a design like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/efTrV.jpg

So my design idea is that I will make a single `Activity` and all the screens will be `Fragment` type and I will do `Fragment Transaction` to change to screens or we can say fragments. This will keep same toolbar across all fragments . But some fragments, can say 4-5 fragments toolbar should have one extra icon. Like in below image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFVsG.jpg

The extra icon is filters icon. So how can I add this extra icon in toolbar for some fragments? Do I have to make an extra `Activity` with different toolbar layout ?

Please provide me some good way to achieve this

Comment: Please, edit the title or content of the question, because now you ask "So how can I add this extra icon in toolbar for some fragments?" (Fragment's menu), but your title is "How to get data in Activity from Fragment" (Pass data between Fragment and Activity)

Answer (score 2):

Every `Fragment` can has different menu.

In Fragment's `onCreate` method add this:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

and after that override `onCreateOptionsMenu` callback in the `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

In fragment

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,Activity.class)
intent.putExtra("pin",pins);
System.out.println(pin);
```

In Activity

```
pined=getIntent().getStringExtra("pin");
System.out.println(pined);
```

Comment: I am asking that do i have to add another activity to get filter icon in some fragment or in required fragment do i have to show filter icon by making it visible / invisible

Answer (score 0):

Put a method to show/hide the third button in your toolbar in the activity class
and access your `activity` in `fragments` and use `setUserVisibleHint` in every `fragment` and you'll know on which `fragment` you want to show that third button.

Answer (score 0):

you can override onCreateOptionsMenu  method in your class and override onOptionsItemSelected 
 try

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
     menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.demo,menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
```

Comment: cam u tell me how can i load that particular image from assets to set that image of menu ....and how to handle click of that image

Comment: u can add icon in your menu file and set attribute inAction values is  ifroom